# Is there a way to split a string in SQL Server 2017 and run another query on each item?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2017, I am running a fairly straightforward query of:

```
SELECT SecCode,Allowed FROM Security
```

And that is returning a fairly straightforward table as shown here:

| SecCode | Allowed |
| --- | --- |
| MNCUPR | GroupA |
| SEC000 | GroupB,GroupC |
| SEC001 | GroupA,GroupC |
| SEC005 | GroupD |
| SEC007 | GroupA,GroupB,GroupD |

I am trying to determine what options I have (if any) to perform a few additional tasks in this query:

1. Split the results in 'Allowed' by comma, giving me separate entities/tokens for each Group in a given row.
2. Run an additional query of: SELECT Users from Users WHERE GroupList LIKE %GROUP_FROM_MAIN_QUERY%

Hopefully returning something like:

| SecCode | Allowed |
| --- | --- |
| MNCUPR | Adam,Alex |
| SEC000 | Billy,Bobby,Charlie,Chuck,Charles |
| SEC001 | Adam,Alex,Charlie,Chuck,Charles |
| SEC005 | Dylan,David |
| SEC007 | Adam,Alex,Billy,Bobby,Dylan,David |

Would this best be handled by a stored procedure? Or some form of a cte?

I'm open to any suggestions, as I am using this as more of a learning experience than anything else.

Comment: You mean `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`...? Though the better question is "Why are you storing denormalised, comma delimited data, in your relational database in the first place?"

Comment: @Larnu - If it was my database, I would be happy to give you an answer. This is from our ERP system, Epicor.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`; there are *literally* **100**'s of duplicates out there on how to use these. Though, again, I strongly recommend fixing the design; if you can't do that, then feed back to whomever can.

Comment: Your previous question involves using STRING_SPLIT() - seems like that can be applied here as well

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: "a stored procedure?" and "some form of a cte" are orthogonal to the actual question you are asking. You can do it with or without them, what you need are `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`